# Abelian categories with tensor product

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, tensor-products, abelian-categories

Is there a standard notion in the literature of abelian category with tensor product?

The definition ought to be wide enough to encompass all the usual examples of abelian categories with standard `tensor product'. I'd guess something like "symmetric monoidal bi-functor $\otimes \colon \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ which preserves finite colimits" would do, but I wonder if there is a reference for this?

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175108/definition-of-a-monoidal-abelian-category).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(\mathcal{A},\otimes)$ be a monoidal category. It is called abelian monoidal if *$\mathcal{A}$ is an abelian category and $\otimes$ is an additive bifunctor* (see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0004160v1.pdf), Section 1.5). An example given the linked paper is the category of bimodules over a ring (in fact any closed abelian monoidal category can be exactly embedded in a bimodule category).

Comment: Thanks. I actually need a bit more, that projectives are flat, but since this notion is pretty wide I can just make an additional hypothesis.